# How to manage QNetworkReply order from QNetworkAccessManager requests

Tags: json, qt, servlets, lambda, qnetworkaccessmanager

I have a Demo Server replying JSON objects only to the client request.

I am planning to use QNetworkAccessManager as the client, this is what I did.

I defined a lambda function handling Server reply

```
        std::function<void(QNetworkReply*)> processReplyLB = [&](QNetworkReply *reply){
        static int cnt = 0;
        std::cout<<"--------------------"<<(++cnt)<<"---------------------"<<std::endl;
        QList<QByteArray> headerList = reply->rawHeaderList();
        foreach (QByteArray header, headerList) {
            std::cout<<header.constData()<<" - "<<reply->rawHeader(header).constData()<<std::endl;
        }

        processResult = false;
        if(reply->error()){
            std::cout<<"REPLY ERROR"<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<reply->errorString().toUtf8().constData()<<std::endl;
        } else {
            QString value = reply->readAll();
            std::cout<<"value = "<<value.toUtf8().constData()<<std::endl;
            QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(value.toUtf8());
            if(doc.isNull()){
                std::cout<<"JSON document is null"<<std::endl;
            }else if(doc.isEmpty()){
                std::cout<<"JSON document is empty"<<std::endl;
            } else if(!doc.isObject()){
                std::cout<<"JSON document is not an object"<<std::endl;
            } else {
                QJsonObject obj = doc.object();
                QString responseStr = obj.value("result").toString();
                processResult = (responseStr == "ok");
                if(obj.contains("message")){
                    QJsonValue messageValue = obj.value("message");
                    std::cout<<messageValue.toString().toUtf8().constData()<<std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
        reply->deleteLater();
        std::cout<<"--------------------"<<(cnt)<<"---------------------"<<std::endl;
    };
```

and I connected this lambda slot to QNetworkAccessManager in two functions used for

1. check if client session does exist on Server(sends a get request).
2. login using id and password (send a post request with parameters).

in main function, if I invoke checkSession() or login() respectively, the result is fine. but if I try to call

```
login();
checkSession();
```

in sequence, then I will get lambda invoked four times with checkSession() result came as the first, following by a null json, login json result and finally another null json.

I know QNetworkAccessManager works asynchronously, EventLoop can solve this problem, but it is not applicable in real development mode due to I am writing a client background service component.

So how can we design this client so that I can make sure login result is processed before checkSession?

BTW, I used Java Servlet for Server without asynchronous. they are just trivial doGet and doPost processes.

Comment: The higher level QT Network classes are intended to be used with eventloop/signals/slots. Maybe you could expain why you think using an event based approach is not applicable in your case?

Comment: @markus-nm someone said the EventLoop is not quite suitable for background service due to it can be affected by UI operations. I am not so sure so I didn't go for that for the first place.

Comment: When you start a QGuiApplication your main thread will create an eventloop for your UI and run in it's context, and it is a bad idea to do heavy work in this eventloop as it will block the UI while it is busy. The solution is to create additional eventloops from within other threads than the UI thread.